# Изменение цвета кнопок. WPF

Tags: wpf

Допустим, что у меня есть кусок кода, который изменяет цвет. Этот кусок кода изменяет только на определённый цвет. А я хочу сделать чтобы к ARGB прибавлялось 10 к цветам. Но не знаю как это сделать.
Может кто-нибудь знает как это сделать?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: Пишите `Расширение разметки` и через нее задавайте цвет.

Comment: С помощью конвертера. Правда, вопрос толком непонятен